# Are there any events triggered when a Google Ad loads

Tags: javascript, adsense

I am trying to do a bunch of stuff after google ads load on the page. I can do this by checking the div ID and other methods available, however, I would want to know if Google provides another way for developers.

I am sure there are javascript events fired, just want to know if developers can tap into these events and use them in their applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the event callback `AdsLoadedEvent.ADS_LOADED` you can subscribe to. There's good documentation available at http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1705827.

You can figure out when the ad is successfully returned by subscribing to the event `AdsLoadedEvent.ADS_LOADED`

```
adsLoader.addEventListener(AdsLoadedEvent.ADS_LOADED, onAdsLoaded);
```